# ¿Cómo hacer responsive para resoluciones específicas?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy creando un sitio para practicar nada más pero tengo un problema con el aspecto responsive en ciertas pantallas de móviles con la opción de pre visualizar en google. En la mayoría de resoluciones/dispositivos se ve bien, pero hay un problema con otros dispositivos que tienen una resolución diferente que no funciona con el responsive que intento.

No sé si me expliqué bien pero esto es lo  que tengo, quiero editarlo para hacerlo más pequeño en esa específica resolución para que la imagen no se vea cortada de un pedazo. La parte de la imagen y texto bajo el carousel aún no lo termino, lo que quiero es fixear el carousel.

Así se ve en la mayoría de resoluciones:

Pantalla completa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Móvil (mayoría de resoluciones)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve el problema (pedazo en blanco en la parte superior del carousel):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código y responsive que uso:

```css
/* Carousel  */
.carousel-item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
}
.image-cover{
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.image-contain{
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.image-custom1{
  background-size: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 411px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 90px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 82px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 280px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 72px;
  }
}
/*Carousel responsive terminado*/
@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .container-fluid {
    height: 250px;
  }
  {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
  }

} /*Se cierra todo*/
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background-color:black;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"> <!-- Número uno -->
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            </li><!-- Número uno -->
            <li class="nav-item active"> <!-- Número dos -->
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Espacio blanco <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            </li><!-- Número dos -->
            <li class="nav-item active"> <!-- Número tres -->
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Espacio blanco <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            </li> <!-- Número tres -->

            <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Contáctanos
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Correo electrónico</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="En construcción..." aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- Comienza a hacer el cuerpo de la página -->
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item image-cover active" style="background-image:url('img/11760.jpg');"> <!-- Primera imagen con texto -->
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Coso de pruebas, actualizate</h5>
              <p>Tremenda goleada del Bayern Munchen Münich vs FC Barcelona</p>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- Primera imagen con texto -->
          
          <div class="carousel-item image-contain" style="background-image: url('img/dos.jpg');"> <!-- Segunda imagen con texto -->
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Coso de pruebas, actualizate</h5>
              <p>Tremenda goleada del Bayern Munchen Münich vs FC Barcelona</p>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- Primera imagen con texto -->
          <div class="carousel-item image-custom1" style="background-image:url('img/comose2.jpg');"> <!-- Tercera imagen con texto -->
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Coso de pruebas, actualizate</h5>
              <p>Tremenda goleada del Bayern Munchen Münich vs FC Barcelona</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- Terminan imagenes -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que parece que pasa aquí es el siguiente:

Se estan mezclando tus media querys con las de Bootstrap

Para entender esto en el navegador, arriba a la izquiera busca la opcion de show media querys rule y podrás ver todos los saltos que hay.

Además la última captura que adjuntas en la visión desde iPad aparece al 75% (se pone por defecto) trata de ponerlo al 100%

Cuando revises todo eso, yo iría verificando donde va dando los saltos de las media query ensanchando el navegador en la version responsive

Como opinión trataría solo de usar las media query de bootstrap y adaptarme a ellas, ya que igualmente la estas usando, y borraría las mías para que no tengas problemas

Answer (score 0):

Primero estás mezclando distintas medias queries, si por ejemplo una va de 576 a 768 ( las de Bootstrap ) tu estás metiendo una por medio de 600. Usa solo las de Bootstrap.

Después empieza a ir maquetando desde xs hasta xxl, de menos a más. Lo que viene ser aplicar el Mobile First, que un concepto de diseño web optimizado para móviles, donde inicialmente se crea una página web para tablets y smartphones, para adaptarla luego a las necesidades de un navegador de escritorio.

Usa solo estas media queries:

```
// X-Small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query for `xs` since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// X-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

// XX-Large devices (larger desktops, 1400px and up)
@media (min-width: 1400px) { ... }
```

Luego solo te queda jugar con el [grid de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) para que se adapte a lo que tienes en mente y no como te pasa en las capturas